# Danger bonus for working in unsafe environment abroad

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, salary, work-experience, europe

Currently we have the possibility for a project in another country. Due to recent news etc. this country is - in my opinion - not very safe for work/travel (there seems to be the need for armed bodyguards etc.) Therefore, people in the company are not very eager to be sent there.

The company is located in Europe. The field is Electronics & IT.
The duration of the stay can vary between 1 week and 3 months.

I am looking for experiences and concrete numbers for potential risk bonuses to get a feeling for the situation and if it´s worth the risk.

**Question:** Are there any good sources for usual bonus rates for working in a dangerous environment abroad?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Workplace! As it was, the question would likely be closed as "very specific" or "unclear what you are asking", since any answer would depend heavily on what country you are looking at, and what part of that country - parts of Mexico are safe, others not. So I took the liberty of editing the question to ask for possible *sources* of such information. This seems to be more on-topic here. Please feel free to edit further.

Comment: Quick google found this, danger pay from the US. 

http://aoprals.state.gov/Web920/danger_pay_all.asp

Comment: In the military we were given ~$150 a month for hazardous duty pay, but we also received a Hostile Fire and Imminent Danger pay, which was $225/month. I know this isn't the military, but I figured this information couldn't hurt. Plus, it's always fun to remember the non-business world times :)

Comment: which country and is it on the FO's high risk list - is it the Ukraine?

Comment: Don't forget that the posting in some areas can invalidate insurance coverage. Special coverage may be needed.

Comment: @s1lv3r U.S sorry

Comment: @s1lv3r I'm not sure what you want me to say?

Comment: It seems like this is not purely an economic decision: To me, my personal safety is worth more than any bonus. There are many kinds of injury which insurance money can never compensate.

Comment: I hope you're not talking about Kiev because you DEFINITELY don't need a bodyguard there.

Answer (score 6):

> Are there any good sources for usual bonus rates for working in a
>   dangerous environment abroad?

These might help:

http://aoprals.state.gov/Web920/hardship.asp

http://aoprals.state.gov/Web920/danger_pay_all.asp

If your company isn't in the US, your country may have an equivalent table.

Comment: Only 35%! for Afghanistan! government rates will be a lot lower as they can order you to go

Comment: And 30% for Mogadishu, Somalia! Private contractors would tack on multiples of these rates.

Comment: Any idea what the difference is between hardship and danger?

Comment: @DavidK at the top of each linked page is a link to a DSSR page which describes the regulations/guidelines for each of the differential types.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this in civil engineering working for Dar Al Handasha in the early 80's; it varied between 80 - 200% as an extra hazard bonus dependent on the country.

The higher rate would be for counties like Angola where there was a civil war in progress.

I believe in Iraq contractor pay was 2 to 3 times higher and you had benefits like all risks insurance.

By the way, for Beirut in the 80's, there was no extra hazard bonus as no one would have been sent just asking to be kidnapped.